# In fortran, is reading namelists from input files much faster than alternatives?

Tags: optimization, input, fortran, fortran90

Many fortran programs read input in the form of namelists. 
A bunch of variables in the program are put into a namelist statement

`namelist /namelist_name/ variable1, variable2, variable3`

and in a `read` call the variables are read with

`read(unit = unit_number, nml = namelist_name)`

The variables are present in a file in the form

```
 &namelist_name
 variable1 = value1
 variable2 = value2
 variable3 = value3
 /
```

My question is: Would a custom implemented way to read variables from files be much slower than this? Are there special optimizations that fortran compilers apply to namelist read calls that can't be applied to normal code to sequentially scan a file and read some characters from it?

Comment: What's your threshold for "much" slower?  Do you have a particular problem where the input of variables is a significant proportion of run time?

Comment: There is a function that reads input that will be called repeatedly. To be honest it is not a bottleneck or anything like that, I'm not gonna optimize it, the question is more of a curiosity thing, the context is just there to make it more concrete.

Comment: I'm not a compiler developer, but one thing to note is that users 'like' namelists for convenience rather than performance.  Hopefully you'll get an answer from someone with insight.

Comment: Sometimes, in coding, especially legacy code, a feature like namelist or assigned gotos or a logical if followed by an arithmetic if, is like a child dying to play with a new toy.  They will look for an  opportunity to use it and, if nobody questions it, they are just left in.  If it is dotted all over thecode, you will find that the coding is unique to just one person.

Comment: namelists in my experience are there because nobody could be bothered to write a proper input parser - after all it's not normally the most interesting part of a code for most scientific code developers.  And as @cup says once a code gets infested with such things, it's very hard to get rid of them

Comment: I don't see how reading data from namelists could be *much faster* than reading from a different form of formatted input file - I think that reading from disk (which will be the same for both approaches) will dominate the time taken, making any possible faster parsing of a namelist irrelevant to timing.  What might make a difference would be dropping a formatted input file (aka text) and using an unformatted input file (aka binary), but for the usual sizes of namelists, there's not much improvement to be wrung out that way either.

Comment: Compared to other modes of data I/O in Fortran, the namelist input style is an extremely flexible method if you were aware of all of its benefits and capabilities (in particular, in Fortran 2003 and 2008). However, speed is not among those benefits, as far as I am aware. I would recommend you to fully become familiar with all the capabilities of the namelist IO before making a decision to change it.

Comment: When you say: "Inconvenient" what do you mean? Can you elaborate what you would prefer?

Comment: @chw21 I'm not going to change the code, it is legacy code and this is not the bottleneck at all anyways, I guess adding the context was a bit confusing, so I deleted it from the question. This question just occurred to me while I was working with the code. I realized namelists were used a lot and I wondered if they were intrinsically faster than some custom way of parsing input. IDK, I guess I would prefer to have pseudo human readable data stored in yaml or json files.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark you made a good point, I guess you are probably right.

Comment: @King what are the good new features of namelists in f03 and f08?

Comment: I am guessing than it is the derived-type IO using user-defined procedures. Until quite recently the compiler support was quite insufficient, but that has changed. I am not going to rewrite my custom parsing into namelists because of that, but it looks interesting although still the syntax of the files is a bit ugly to my liking.